# 70s book with a young Hawaian girl diving among rocks that used to be human, includes the goddess Pele

Tags: story-identification, books, young-adult

It was a book, published sometime in the 1970's. I remember checking it out of either a school or public library.

It's set in Hawaii and the main character is a young girl who spends a lot of time diving, and finds underwater caves. There's a mythological element as I believe she has a conversation with [Pele](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pele_(deity)).

There's also some kind of legend about some underwater rocks having once been human.